# Where can I find texts that describe topic-specific events? 

Tags: text, nlp, datasource, semantics, corpus

So, some background: I'm trying to train a ML system to answer questions about events, where both the event descriptions and questions are posed in natural language; the event descriptions are constrained to being single sentences.

So far the main problem with this has been locating a corpus that describes events with a limited enough vocabulary to pose similar questions across all of the events (e.g. if all of the events involved chess, I could reasonably ask 'what piece moved?' and an answer could be drawn from a decent percentage of the event description sentences).

With that in mind, I'm hoping to find a text source that is tightly focused around describing events within some fairly limited topic (more along the lines of chess commentary than a chess forum, for example).

While I've had some luck with a corpus of [air-traffic controller dialogs](http://www.ldc.upenn.edu/Catalog/byType.jsp), most of sentences aren't typical English (they involve a lot of Charlie, Tango, etc.). However, if the format is as I've described then the actual topic of focus is irrelevant, so long as it has one.

Since I plan on building my own corpus out of this text, no tagging is necessary.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.  You'll get better responses, and reduce the risk of getting closed, if you summarize what you're looking for in the form of a question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Reuters corpus has a fairly monotonous content (commercial news; CEO appointments, mergers and acquisitions, major deals, etc); I am more familiar with the multilingual v2 but IIRC the v1 corpus was monolingual English. These will be multiple-sentence news stories, but in keeping with journalistic conventions, you can expect the first sentence to form a reasonable gist of the full story. http://about.reuters.com/researchandstandards/corpus/

You might also look at other TREC and especially MUC competition materials; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_Understanding_Conference

Comment: Wow, both of these look like great sources. After I gain access to Reuters and track down the corpus the MUC's used I'll see if they'll be useful for my purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered Usenet? It has a bunch of idiosyncratic conventions of its own but something like `rec.food.cooking` would seem to broadly fit your description. http://groups.google.com/group/rec.food.cooking/ Have a look at e.g. `rec.sports.hockey` or `rec.games.video.arcade` as well. There is also the 20 Newsgroups corpus if you are looking for a canonical, well-known corpus, and it contains at least some sports-related newsgroup material.  http://people.csail.mit.edu/jrennie/20Newsgroups/

(Maybe in your country the "general public" is comfortable with baseball. Over here it would be football, you know, the kind where you can't use your hands.)

Comment: These are interesting corpora, but despite having a decently defined topic, they don't appear to describe events per se. Its my fault for being too vague before; I've edited the question to better describe what I'm looking for.